# Telerik filter function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a portion of **JavaScript** that runs on document ready. However, when i use the filtering of ***telerik***, after successful filter the function that was on document ready is not being registered.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         // Match all link elements with href attributes within the content div
         $('#image1').qtip({
             content: {
                 text: true
             },
             style: {
                 classes: 'qtip-rounded qtip-shadow',
             },
             position: {
                 my: 'top center',  // Position my top left...
                 at: 'bottom center', // at the bottom right of...
                 target: $('.selector') // my target
             }
             //position: {
             //    target: 'mouse',
             //}
         });
});
```

Is there any function of ***telerik*** that gets invoked when we click any of the dropdown value of the filtering provided by telerik. If so, i could register the javascript function from the codebehind. Or, if i could be acknowledged with any other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using *Telerik Ajax Controls for ASP.NET* then it is normal behaviour that after filtering, a postback (or async postback) is issued.
Ajax async post backs cannot be intercepted by jQuery's ready function because of the way Microsoft Ajax works.

```
$(function(){
     //this will only be triggered on the response to the first request
});
```

You should be using Microsoft Ajax syntax instead in order to intercept Ajax responses...

```
var mngInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

mngInstance.add_endRequest(endReq);
mngInstance.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

function endReq(sender, args){
    //executes after an async request ends
}

function pageLoaded(sender, args){
    //executes after the whole page is loaded after an async postback
}
```

Be aware that you will need to a `RadScriptManager` to the page (or master page).
For more infor check the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks i rebinded the plugin in the endReq, which solved the problem for me :)